# Firebase - is there anyway to query in() Rest API?

Tags: rest, parse-platform, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm new to Firebase. I got stuck with Firebase query limitation, honestly I did research a lot in Stackoverflow and other pages as well but I can not find out a solution for my app. Appreciate a lot for your help.

***Expected result:**

- I want to make a dashboard that shows all users who are the friend in Facebook with the user logging in.

***What I did in Parse.com**

- Getting all friend's facebook ID and save to a string like "123892841, 839183901, 1093019301"
- In parse.com database, I query: select * from users where FACEBOOK_ID in ["123892841, 839183901, 1093019301"]
- So I can get these 3 users

***I got stuck with Firebase**

- I only found a way to query a user with specific Facebook_ID: "orderBy='FB_ID'&equalTo='123892841'"

***Conclusion**

- Is there any good way to solve my problem? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: @Alex: that question is about querying on multiple properties. This question is about multiple values. It's closer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786, but unfortunately that doesn't apply to the REST API.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My mistake, thanks for your clarification

Comment: I guess your title REST - API is now nonsense? If not you can do a workaround to make the Firebase SDK Functions (if you use the SDK) synchron instead asynchron as it is because thats a problem with REST